# Angular unit test routerLink state

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-router, angular-routerlink

Im passing data between angular (version 8) components A & B using [`state`](https://medium.com/ableneo/how-to-pass-data-between-routed-components-in-angular-2306308d8255), example:

```
<a routerLink="/componentB" [state]="{data: {hello: 'world'}}">Go To ComponentB</a>
```

In ComponentB, i'm reading data:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.data = history.state.data.hello;
}
```

Everything is working in live webapp, but I can't seem to replicate the same in the jasmine test.
Unit test goes like this:

```
setup();
...
fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(`a`).click();

fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
  expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(`p`)).toContain('world');
}
```

Navigation worked, prior to adding `this.data = ...` to `ngOnInit()`, but now there is null pointer exception. Effectively `state` is `null`, but I can't figure out why. Everything is working when running webapp live, but Jasmine unit test is failing.

I know I can add `history.pushState({data: {hello: 'world'}}, '', '');` to setup, but I want for real data to be passed from componentA to componentB during unit testing. What am I missing? Why data from one component does not transfer into another via `state`?

Comment: @Melr did you find any solution ?

Comment: @ApurvaPathak - I didn't find how to unit test the above solution. I decided not to use the solution at all. What I decided to do is to pass all needed data via url params, even entire object can be encoded base64 and passed. Perhaps it is not the best solution but it is unit testable solution.

P.S: Im still hoping that someone will answer the question :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to push your state in the `beforeeach`;
something like:

```
history.pushState("hello", "world");
```

Comment: I need to amend that statement.  I am basically working through this myself.  The above statement will pass the tests but to set the state correctly history.pushState needs to be set like this for your data flow:
history.pushState({data:.... and I just noticed the statement about history.pushState...and basically to answer your actual question is that is not how unit tests work.  You have to mock your data for each test suite.